# How to settle a value in a list that contains a list?

Tags: python

I want to make a simple array `b`, and set `b[0][0]` to be `1`. However, `b[1][0]`, `b[2][0]` and `b[3][0]` changed as well. How to solve this?

```
>>> a=[0]*5
>>> b=[a]*4
>>> b
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> b[0][0]
0
>>> b[0][0]=1
>>> b
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

List `b` was created with list `a`, and all rows in `b` reference the same list object as `a`:

You can avoid this behavior by using a copy of `a`:

```
b = [a.copy()]
```

And to avoid each row in `b` pointing to the same object:

```
b = [a.copy() for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: Then, how could I create a 4*5 array with default value 0? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/240205/3125566

Comment: If in this way, how could I change the value in the position I want.

Comment: The same way you would in the first case: `b[0][0]=1`